# how to get the input on the textbox in pyqt using another py script

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have these 2 scripts. First contains ui using pyqt5,this contains some textbox and buttons. The second one contains the functions of the buttons( i mean what it will do).For now I just want to display in the terminal on what is written in the textbox. The problem is i can't get/print/display the input text in the textbox using the second py. I have this button(upload button) which must display this text in the terminal when click.

I have tried to import the second py to first. Then i connect the button.
       butUpld.clicked.connect(py2.up)

for the second py i also connect it to the first one

```
This is the first py file name py1.py

import os, glob, sys, time
import py2
from PyQt5.Qt import QApplication, QClipboard, QUrl
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QWidget, QPlainTextEdit,   QLabel, QGridLayout, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QTextEdit, QMessageBox, QComboBox, QTabWidget, QFormLayout, QHBoxLayout, QRadioButton, QCheckBox, QVBoxLayout, QFileDialog, QButtonGroup
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, Qt

qt_app = QApplication(sys.argv)

class Layoutexe(QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Layoutexe, self).__init__(parent)
        self.tab1 = QWidget()
        self.tab2 = QWidget()

        self.addTab(self.tab1," ")
        self.addTab(self.tab2," ")
        self.tab1UI()
        self.tab2UI()
        self.setWindowTitle(" ")
        self.setFixedSize(900,1000)

    def tab1UI(self):
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox1 = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox2 = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox3 = QHBoxLayout()

        labelPath = QLabel("PATH:")
        tboxPath = QLineEdit(self)
        butSrch = QPushButton("Search", self)
        butClr = QPushButton("Clear", self)
        hbox.addStretch()
        hbox.addWidget(labelPath)
        hbox.addWidget(tboxPath)
        hbox.addWidget(butSrch)
        hbox.addStretch()
        hbox.addWidget(butClr)
        vbox.addLayout(hbox)

        radbutLst = QRadioButton("Latest")
        radbutMnl = QRadioButton("Manual")
        hbox1.addWidget(radbutLst)
        hbox1.addWidget(radbutMnl)
        hbox1.addStretch()
        vbox.addLayout(hbox1)

        labelEV = QLabel("Event:")
        tboxEV = QLineEdit(self)
        hbox2.addWidget(labelEV)
        hbox2.addWidget(tboxEV)
        hbox2.addStretch()
        vbox.addLayout(hbox2)

        butUpld = QPushButton("UPLOAD", self)
        hbox3.addStretch()
        hbox3.addWidget(butUpld)
        hbox3.addStretch()
        vbox.addLayout(hbox3)

        vbox.addStretch()
        self.tab1.setLayout(vbox)

    butUpld.clicked.connect(py2.up)

    def tab2UI(self):
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        layout = QHBoxLayout()

    def run(self):
        self.show()
        qt_app.exec_()

app = Layoutexe()
app.run()



this the second py file named py2.py

import os, glob
import py1

def up():
    a = gui.rep.tab1U.tboxEV
    print(a.text())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

**py1.py**

```
import sys
#import os, glob, time

from PyQt5.Qt import QApplication, QClipboard, QUrl
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QWidget, QPlainTextEdit,   QLabel, QGridLayout, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QTextEdit, QMessageBox, QComboBox, QTabWidget, QFormLayout, QHBoxLayout, QRadioButton, QCheckBox, QVBoxLayout, QFileDialog, QButtonGroup
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, Qt

import py2         

qt_app = QApplication(sys.argv)

class Layoutexe(QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Layoutexe, self).__init__(parent)

        self.tab1 = QWidget()
        self.tab2 = QWidget()

        self.addTab(self.tab1," ")
        self.addTab(self.tab2," ")
        self.tab1UI()
        self.tab2UI()
        self.setWindowTitle(" ")
        self.setFixedSize(900,1000)

    def tab1UI(self):
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox1 = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox2 = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox3 = QHBoxLayout()

        labelPath = QLabel("PATH:")
        tboxPath = QLineEdit(self)
        butSrch = QPushButton("Search", self)
        butClr = QPushButton("Clear", self)
        hbox.addStretch()
        hbox.addWidget(labelPath)
        hbox.addWidget(tboxPath)
        hbox.addWidget(butSrch)
        hbox.addStretch()
        hbox.addWidget(butClr)
        vbox.addLayout(hbox)

        radbutLst = QRadioButton("Latest")
        radbutMnl = QRadioButton("Manual")
        hbox1.addWidget(radbutLst)
        hbox1.addWidget(radbutMnl)
        hbox1.addStretch()
        vbox.addLayout(hbox1)

        labelEV = QLabel("Event:")
        self.tboxEV = QLineEdit(self)
        hbox2.addWidget(labelEV)
        hbox2.addWidget(self.tboxEV)
        hbox2.addStretch()
        vbox.addLayout(hbox2)

        butUpld = QPushButton("UPLOAD", self)
        hbox3.addStretch()
        hbox3.addWidget(butUpld)
        hbox3.addStretch()
        vbox.addLayout(hbox3)

        vbox.addStretch()
        self.tab1.setLayout(vbox)

        butUpld.clicked.connect(lambda _, s=self: py2.up(s))             # +++

    def tab2UI(self):
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        layout = QHBoxLayout()

    def run(self):
        self.show()
        qt_app.exec_()

app = Layoutexe()
app.run()
```

**py2.py**

```
#import os, glob
#import py1

def up(self):
#    a = gui.rep.tab1U.tboxEV
    a = self.tboxEV
    print(a.text())
```

[image]

Comment: It worked! thank you! can you explain why did you change tboxEV = QLineEdit(self) into self.tboxEV = QLineEdit(self), I mean the difference. and why  use butUpld.clicked.connect(lambda _, s=self: py2.up(s)) instead of just butUpld.clicked.connect(py2.up)

Comment: @p_p  `self.tboxEV` - makes the `tboxEV` object an attribute of the `Layoutexe` class. So, the `self.tboxEV` object can be accessed from another method / function.

The `up` function does not know anything about the existence of the `Layoutexe` object, so we must pass it to this function.
One way to do this is `butUpld.clicked.connect (lambda _, s = self: py__2.up (s))`